# How to use upsert params with feathershjs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, feathersjs

I have a config's model as below:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const mongooseClient = app.get('mongooseClient');
  const { Schema } = mongooseClient;
  const config = new Schema({
    year: { type: Number, required: true },
    group: { type: Array, required: true },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    format: { type: String, required: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  }, { collection: 'config' });

  return mongooseClient.model('config', config);
};
```

in my js file I have service name "config". I try use patch method with upsert:true but it's not working.

```
var data = { year: 2018, group: [], title: "", format:""  }
var params = { query: { year: 2018 }, mongoose: { upsert: true } }

app.service('config').patch(null, data, params).then(function(result){
console.log(result);
});
```

In my collection not exists any document with the 2017 year field so as you can see above should be created a new document but I receive all the time empty array: []. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good. The only reason I can think of for this not to work is that the service is called from `client`. The only part of `params` that will be passed to the server is the `query`. You can see it [here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#params).

So my suggestion is that add that to your query? maybe do something like;

`var params = { query: { year: 2018, $mongoose: { upsert: true } }`

Then in your hooks you can check if `$mongoose` exists and add it to the params and do not forget to delete it in your query.

You can also make use of [`paramsForServer`](https://feathers-plus.github.io/v1/feathers-hooks-common/index.html#paramsFromClient) && [`paramsFromClient`](https://feathers-plus.github.io/v1/feathers-hooks-common/index.html#paramsFromClient).